# Git for Windows silent installation without "Credential Manager"

Tags: git, inno-setup, git-for-windows

I want to install git (Git-2.14.1-64-bit.exe for example) using command line without setup **credential.manager**.

I've tried to find options in https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/installer/install.iss.

Any suggestion how to do this using flags or environment variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [`ReplayChoice` function](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/ac0be86cb640184dfc0a5501d8d7970b50c406da/installer/install.iss#L667) and its use in the [`InitializeWizard` event function](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/ac0be86cb640184dfc0a5501d8d7970b50c406da/installer/install.iss#L1311), this command-line switch should do:

```
/o:UseCredentialManager=Disabled
```

(or any other value except for `Enabled`)